# How to select a NIC for Jabber server to use

Tags: jabber, network-adapter

There are two NICs available in my environment, and Jabber server defaults to the one I use for my Intranet connection.

I can't find any configuration option to change that, so the only way I can make Jabber use the other NIC is to disable the first one.

How can I change Jabber's behavior in this case?

Edit: I use Jive jabber server

Comment: what jabber server, specifically?

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention which Jabber implementation you are using, but most of the allow for the configuration of the specific IP and port combination to listen on. This in effect determines the interface that is used. Check the documentation for your specific Jabber implementation.